# DJANGO - Computing every item unitprice and quantity

Tags: python, django

what i want is to compute every item product not the total average, how do i compute every product unitprice multipy by its quantity?

***I just want to get the total amount of every item, but how do i do that? what should I use? aggregate or annotate?***

I use aggregate for getting the total amount of all product

```
total = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(
            id__in=cart.values_list('id')
        ).aggregate(
            total=Sum(
                F('unitprice') * F('quantity'),
                output_field=FloatField(),
            )
        )['total']
        print('aggregate', total)
```

and this is my logic on how to get the the total amount of per product

```
total_amount_of_product = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(
    id__in=cart.values_list('id')).annotate(total_per_item=Sum(F('unitprice') * F('quantity'),
                output_field=FloatField(),))
item_totals = [item.total_per_item for item in total_amount_of_product]
```

this is the result in my html

[image]

this is how i print to the html

```
<td class="cart__cell--total"><span class="cart__item-total">₱ {{item_totals}}</span></td>
```

this is my models.py

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(models.Model):

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer, 
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Client Account")

    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name="Product")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=1)
    
    unitprice = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Don't show what you did right... Show what you are having problem with. So, show us your `models.py` of concerned class, `views.py` from where you will render template and the `template`

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane i posted my models.py

Comment: By **every product** you mean, **each product**. Right?

Comment: exactly mr @BiploveLamichhane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method in `models.py` to return what you want like:

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Client Account")
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Product")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=1)
    unitprice = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def totalAmountOfProduct(self):
        return self.unitprice * self.quantity
```

In your views.py:

```
all_products = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.all()
```

In your template:

```
{% for item in all_products %}
    <td class="cart__cell--total"><span class="cart__item-total">₱ {{item.totalAmountOfProduct}}
{% endfor %}
```